# What is the best way to build an Angular multi-step wizard?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular and I am wanting to build a multi-step wizard using Angular.

The requirement is basically to facilitate the application process for a store card in the application. I need to develop 3 processes / 3 multi step wizards.

So my current solution is:

I have built 8 shared Angular Components representing different steps in the process and I want to use these shared components across the 3 multi step wizards using Angular.

As an example, I have the first Multi Step done in the following way:

I created a Parent Component:

```
<div class="steps-form col s11">
   <div class="steps-row setup-panel">
       <div class="steps-step" *ngFor="let step of wizManager.Steps">
            step.StepName
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="card-content" >
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)">
</router-outlet>
</div>
```

I use the OnActivate on router-outlet event:

```
onActivate(componentRef: any) {
        this.currentComponent = componentRef;
}
```

Within the parent I have a Service that I use to validate each step on next:

```
next(step: WizardStepDTO) {
        this._slimLoadingBarService.start();
        this.loadingControl.showloading();

        //Validate Current Step first 
        if (step.RequiresValidation) {
            this.ValidateCurrentStep(step, this.currentComponent);
        }

        //save data
        if (step.ValidationResult.FormStepState == StepState.ValidAndReadyForProcessing) {
            this.ProcessCurrentStep(step, this.currentComponent);
        }

        if (step.ValidationResult.FormStepState == StepState.Complete) {

            var newStep = this.wizManager.Steps.filter(item => item.StepId === step.StepId + 1)[0];

            //set current step to next step
            this.wizManager.CurrentStep = newStep;


                this.router.navigate([newStep.StepView]);

        this._slimLoadingBarService.complete();
        this.loadingControl.hideloading();
    }
```

I use the service to keep track of each step and validate. I then use ComponentRef above to set/get any values from each child component.

The routing for the MultiStep is as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent, canLoad: [CanLoadGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'step1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'step1',
                component: Step1Component
            },
            {
                path: 'step2',
                component: Step2Component
            },
            {
                path: 'step3',
                component: Step3Component
            }
        ]
    }

];
```

After all of that, my questions are:

1. Before I start with the backend, is there a better way to do this in Angular? I am interested to know how to validate each child.
2. What would be the best way to navigate between steps? At the moment I am using `this.router.navigate([newStep.StepView])` but I am not sure if there is a better way.
3. I would like to save the state of the wizard as the user navigates through and if the user stops midway, I would like to load it from where they stopped. Can someone please suggest an efficient way to do this if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but I did something similar with a multi-tab edit page. You can find it in my github here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing in the app/movies/edit folder.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have removed a request that was euphemistically termed "make me a quick Plunkr". Readers will often call that "a request for free work". While someone may well indeed go to those lengths for you, it is best to keep your requests small, given they are being made of volunteers. I suspect that the question may be either too broad or opinion-based for Stack Overflow anyway, but we'll see.

Comment: @DeborahK, Thank you. I actually used your GitHub when I started.

Comment: @halfer, Thank you. Noted. Will take these into account on my future posts.